# Fundamental Group of an n-dimensional manifold with finite k punctures

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, fundamental-groups

> **Problem:** Show that $\pi_1(M\setminus${k points}$) = \pi_1(M)$, where $M$ is an n-dimensional manifold ($n\ge 3)$ and k is a positive integer.

---

In class, we went over the proof for the above problem for the case $k=1$. I am now trying to scale it for any positive integer $k$.

Let $D_i$ be an open ball around puncture $i$, where $i = 1,...,k$.

To use Van Kampen's theorem, I need the intersection between the balls and $M\setminus${k points} 
to be simply connected.

To ensure that this is indeed the case,

1. Do I need to specify that the open balls around each puncture overlap?
2. Since the union of open sets is open, can I just consider the open ball with all k punctures, or is this not possible for all manifolds?

Comment: If you know how to prove this for one point you know how to prove it for all points by induction.

Comment: hint: if $M$ is a manifold of dimension $n$, then so is $M\setminus\{x\}$ for some puncture point $x\in M$. (Prove this)